# smart-table row selection enable disable using script

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am working on on page where I need to show row selected and I need to populate that selected row in form next to that grid, its working properly but I am trying to implement disable row selection when user is editing any existing row, please let me know how to resolve this. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have something similar to this in your code:

```
<tr st-select-row="schedule" st-select-mode="multiple" ng-repeat="schedule in displaySchedules>
```

You should remove the attribute st-select-row="schedule" to disable selection functionality when editing flag is true or whatever is the condition you need to meet.